# Index Match to get a value before a date with a 2nd condition

Tags: excel

consider the following data on `sheet_x`

```
Name, Date,    Area
Jon,  30/3/18,  1
Mo,   30/3/18,  1
Ti,   30/3/18,  2
Tai,  30/3/18,  2
```

on `sheet_y` i'll have a date in cell `A2`

`30/03/18` for example

i'll use the following formula to get all the names before on a certain date

```
{INDEX(sheet_x!A2:A4,SMALL(IF(sheet_x!B2:B4=A2,ROW(sheet_x!B2:B4))mod((row()-row(a2)),11)))}
```

now this is great - it returns all the names that occur on that date when I drag this down, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add a second condition in to the formula which only fetches all the names on the date for Area that i specify. would anyone know how to do this?

apologies if this is a badly formatted question - if I can phrase this better please let me know.

EDIT :

The reason I want to list this by date is to create a calendar of when a certain person is on Holiday but make the excel spreadsheet dynamic so the user can choose their Area.

so I have the following sheet with dates and I use the if formula to only select the the date in question. the mod formula, as I understand at mar 30 & mar 31

```
    {INDEX(sheet_x!A2:A4,SMALL(IF(sheet_x!B2:B4=A2,ROW(sheet_x!B2:B4))mod((row()-row(**b2**)),11)))} 
# B2 = Mar 31 a2 = Mar 30


Mar 30, Mar 31, April 01,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do the job

- Enter a header in cell `D1` p.e. `Results`
- Enter this formula in cell `D2` en confirm as array formula

  ```
  ={IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,SMALL(IF(1=((--(Sheet_y!$A$1>$B$2:$B$5))*(--(Sheet_y!$B$1=$C$2:$C$5))),ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1,""),ROW()-1)),"")}
  ```
- I'm assuming your second criteria (area) to be in `Sheet_y!$B$1`
- Drag down the formula

Below my results with referenced cells for criteria 1 `F1` and criteria2 `F2`:
[image]

P.S.: I assumed (by your question's title) you wanted results before criteria1. If it must be the results on that specific date, you can just change the `>` for a `=`.

Comment: Thanks for this - I can't however get the formula to work - after staring and trying out  different permutations I think I may know why. I'll update my initial Q so it's clear.

Comment: @Datanovice, I'm afraid I don't understand your question in that case. Maybe you can rework your question so it's more clear. You have A) Two criteria, B) First is a single date, C) second is a specific area? Now do you want all dates before the first criteria or only records that match that criteria.

Comment: never mind me - figured it out, you are an absolute legend! i would have never been able to figure this out.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hey buddy final Q, any reason why this would not work when the indexed data is on a different sheet? works on the same page but not when its on a different one.. been driving me crazy but it's the only change I can see (Essentially A:C sits on a raw_data tab and D:F sit on my dynamic page)

Comment: @Datanovice. Are you sure you have got the reference right? Mine works perfectly. p.e: `Sheet2!$A$1>$B$2:$B$5`...